# How to download Power BI report data set after publish and shared link for anonymous user

Tags: dataset, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I have published the Power BI report from there we need to download the dataset/export it as an Excel sheet.

How can I achieve the same?

[image]

and my published we link is here.
[enter link description here](https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNGMxN2ZmNjUtZWI3NS00ZWRmLTlhYWMtMzJiZDhkZGUwY2JiIiwidCI6IjcxZDE3MmJhLTJjOTQtNDA3Ni1iNmQ1LTg0Y2Y4YWJlOTE4NCJ9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't export data from report published to web. This is one of the [limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web#limitations) of this feature:

> **Limitations**
>
> Publish to web is supported for the vast majority of data sources and reports in the Power BI service, however, the following are not currently supported or available with Publish to web:
>
> - Reports using row level security.
> - Reports using any Live Connection data source, including Analysis Services Tabular hosted on-premises, Analysis Services Multidimensional, and Azure Analysis Services.
> - Reports shared to you directly or through an organizational content pack.
> - Reports in a group in which you are not an edit member.
> - "R" Visuals are not currently supported in Publish to web reports.
> - **Exporting Data from visuals in a report, which has been published to the web.**
> - ArcGIS Maps for Power BI visuals.
> - Reports containing report-level DAX measures.
> - Single sign-on data query models.
> - Secure confidential or proprietary information.
> - Shared and certified datasets.
> - The automatic authentication capability provided with the Embed option doesn't work with the Power BI JavaScript API. For the Power BI JavaScript API, use the user owns data approach to embedding.

Comment: Maybe there is some kind of workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the visual header and then you should be able use the ellipses to get to the data options.

[image: Enable visual headers]

Also make sure the visual headers are turned on for the target visuals.

[image: Enable header on a visual]

You should then see the option to export.

[image: Export data from a visual]

Find more [info in the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-export)